# Uniformly non-square Banach spaces are reflexive

Tags: functional-analysis

in this theorem of the paper "Uniformly Non-Square Banach Spaces" of Robert C. James:

**Theorem:** A Banach space is refiexive if its unit ball is uniformly non-square.

why $K _{n}$  is positive, monotone increasing and for any number $r$ with $1> r > 1-\delta $, there is a positive number $\epsilon $ and an $N$ such that

\begin{equation*}
\frac{K _{n} - \epsilon}{K _{n} + 2\epsilon} > r > 1 - \delta
\end{equation*}?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\epsilon =\frac {(1-r)K_1}{6}.$ For all $n$ we have $$0<1-\frac {K_n-\epsilon}{K_n+2\epsilon}=\frac {3\epsilon}{K_n+2\epsilon}<\frac {3\epsilon}{K_n}\leq \frac {3\epsilon}{K_1}=\frac {1-r}{2}<1-r<\delta .$$

Comment: Thanks for helping :)